# How to use If else condition in jquery template for span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Working on mvc4 web api project with jquery template.
Depending upon `database value` I want to `show the stars span class` on View.

```
<div>
<span class="font-icon-star"></span>
<span class="font-icon-star"></span>
<span class="font-icon-star"></span>
<span class="font-icon-star"></span>
<span class="font-icon-star-line"></span>
</div>${Rating}

{{If Rating = 4 }}
then it should show 4 full stars and 1 empty star
```

> How can i make this dymanic depending upon $Rating value?

[image]

Comment: Do these elements start out with any class already set?

Comment: class="ratingpointgrppage" but your posted answer works good for me :)

Comment: I haven't posted an answer, yet.

Comment: oops previously posted answer someone deleted that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>
   ${Rating}
   <span class="${Rating > 0 ? 'font-icon-star' : 'font-icon-star-line'}"></span>
   <span class="${Rating > 1 ? 'font-icon-star' : 'font-icon-star-line'}"></span>
   <span class="${Rating > 2 ? 'font-icon-star' : 'font-icon-star-line'}"></span>
   <span class="${Rating > 3 ? 'font-icon-star' : 'font-icon-star-line'}"></span>
   <span class="${Rating > 4 ? 'font-icon-star' : 'font-icon-star-line'}"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks .. it is too long code , I need to make it dynamic.. but works best for me :)

Comment: undeleted since it was referenced in the comments - for a non-js solution

Comment: in a way that it does not use JS.  This is called EL (Expression language)

Comment: Well, live and learn! I'd never even heard of that before, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
$('span').addClass('font-icon-star-line');

$('span').filter(function(){ 
   return $(this).index() <= rating; 
}).removeClass('font-icon-star-line').addClass('font-icon-star');
```

Comment: @ashuthinks Yes, probably.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$('span.ratingpointgrppage').addClass(function(i){
    return 'font-icon-star' + (Rating > i ? '-line' : '');
});
```

The above assumes you want to keep the original class-name (`ratingpointgrppage`) if not, however:

```
$('span.ratingpointgrppage').removeClass('ratingpointgrppage').addClass(function(i){
    return 'font-icon-star' + (Rating > i ? '-line' : '');
});
```

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).